# In WebRTC, when one user needs TURN but the other user does not, will traffic between them all go through TURN server?

Tags: webrtc

What is WebRTC's behavior in establishing peer connection between following two users?

- User A's network involves NAT/router such that direct connection to it is not possible, and it requires TURN relay.
- User B's network can support direct connection.

I assume traffic from user B to user A must go through TURN server.
However, does traffic from user A to user B also have to go through TURN?

In other words, when one of two users require TURN due to network constraints, will all traffic between them go through TURN server regardless of whether or not the other user supports direct connection?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't matter about A's network or B's network in isolation. It matters about the network path between A and B. If the only way A can connect to B is via a TURN server then that's also the only way B can connect to A (barring any asymmetric firewall rules or other crazy stuff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ICE protocol will attempt a direct connections in either direction: if one peer is directly reachable from the other, then traffic will take the direct route in both directions.  It is only if neither peer can reach the other that TURN will be used.

Note, however, that ICE might time out before the direct connection is established, so even if the peers are reachable, the data might occasionally go through the TURN server.